# How to store a variable after button activated, to use for next calculation? (in Swift)

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have simple app that does a financial calculation when button pressed.  I want to store that result into a variable to have for next time user hit calculation button. Like  `var lastResult = currentResult`.

Then user changed inputs and hits calculate button, I desire to take that new `currentResult` get the difference with `lastResult`. Simple really, but... I can do not know where or how in my `viewController` code to do that.

Will work if I can store variable after calculation is done, then use it for the next time. But I can not figure this out. thank you, Mike.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global variable outside of any function but inside your class-body. Like that:

```
class YourCalcClass: UIViewController{
    var lastResult:Double?
}
```

Then in your method you just set the variable value:

```
lastResult = currentResult
```

That way, the variable is stored.

Comment: tried no errors but not getting the value. wonder why? can we email?

Comment: Christian or anyone I am still very stuck... can someone please help me.  I can email if easier, miketradr@gmail.com thank you so much.  Simple problemI thought but I am stuck still.

Answer (score 0):

Like some other object oriented languages (ex. C#) swift does not support static variables within class methods (variables that persist between calls to the method. This is likely due to thread safety issues.

Like Christian said above, class level variables (variables that are declared outside of your IBAction methods but in the same class) can be used for this.  As your program complexity increases (especially coordination of data values between instances of your classes) it is often beneficial to put such data into a separate model.

You can read more about this structure called MVC or Model-View-Controller on the Apple site:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html

Wikipedia also has a very good page on it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Answer (score 0):

here is Simple code and app...

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var yearsEntered: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultOut: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priorOut: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var differenceOut: UILabel!

    @IBAction func calcButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        var age = yearsEntered.text.toInt()

        var result = age! * 7

        resultOut.text = "Age is \(result)"

        var priorResult = result

        var diff = result - priorResult

        priorOut.text = "Prior \(priorResult)"
        differenceOut.text = "Difference \(diff)"

        //where do I save and how to recall the priorResult to use for difference???

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Still NOT answered can some one PLEASE help me! Frustrating!!!! Trying to store a global variable when calculation (button) is pressed... Then recall and use it for the next calculation, but then update it after it is used with a new value... (Only need to store while app is running not for future) Simply desire to compare one result with prior result is all!!!! How or where is this done, I tried but get declaration errors???? Where do I place the saves and calls? please be specific, I have tried all week on this sadly. Should be simple! I am new and learning. Well trying to. thank you. –

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work for you if the instance of the UIViewController that you are using does not go out of scope. If this is not your main view I think you will have issues whenever this view controller is popped of the view stack. In that case you will need to learn how to use the prepareForSegue function to set values in your view controller from the calling view controller and keep the data (prior result) there. This is really done properly using delegation.

Because the ios model of program design is MVC (as referred to in my answer above), any sort of data that persists longer than an instance of a class needs to be owned by either a class instance further up the hierarchy (ex. the UIViewController instance that created the sub-UIViewController instance) or in a separate model.  Dealing with both of these cases usually means learning about 'delegation' which is how data is usually passed back up the hierarchy.

This is probably a good next step for you to learn.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var yearsEntered: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultOut: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priorOut: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var differenceOut: UILabel!

    // variables declared here (not inside methods) last as long as the the view exists (the instance of your view controller class) 
    var priorResult = 0  // you could also use an optional for this

    @IBAction func calcButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        var age = yearsEntered.text.toInt()

        var result = age! * 7

        resultOut.text = "Age is \(result)"

        var diff = result - priorResult

        // This line needs to be below the the above line.  In your example code you were doing this first leading to a diff of zero every time.
        priorResult = result

        priorOut.text = "Prior \(priorResult)"
        differenceOut.text = "Difference \(diff)"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```